# How to detect incoming and outgoing call END event in my Iphone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, events, call, core-telephony

Here is a scenario:
I make a call from my application .When the call ends i need to fire a event such as calling a web service .How can do with CTcallcenter in core telephony frame work ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [Cellular Call States](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCall/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Cellular_Call_States) for this purpose

**CTCallStateDialing**

The call state, before connection is established, when the user initiates the call.

**CTCallStateIncoming**

The call state, before connection is established, when a call is incoming but not yet answered by the user.

**CTCallStateConnected**

The call state when the call is fully established for all parties involved.

**CTCallStateDisconnected**

The call state upon call termination.