# Is there a way that we can get delegate methods when we receive a phone, finish a phone call etc. in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiapplicationdelegate

Let's say I want to call a method after my phone call was finished in my application. Is it possible to do that? I know about using `UIApplicationDelegate` Methods where I can use the methods:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

This might not be the case since its not necessary that the app will call this method specifically after finishing the phone call. Can be other interruptions.

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

This might not be the case since its not necessary that the app will call this method specifically when we get a phone call. Can be other interruptions.

Are there any notifications that I am missing?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802084/how-to-detect-incoming-and-outgoing-call-end-event-in-my-iphone-app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319805/detecting-call-state-in-ios4

Answer (score 1):

Bring Users Back to your Application after they End the Call

See [this link](http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/09/06/bring-users-back-to-your-application-after-they-end-the-call/)